# Databinding on LINQtoSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

i need to bind data to grid view on linq to sql dynamically i know basic way to do that but i have problem becuase need to join two table and get the data from two table let say need tp select product but also need to add category name as field. please help me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write code for the join on OnQueryCreated event. Please have a look at the article here for a working code:

http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1584

Comment: of cz that's really what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I can't do much to help without a more detailed definition of your problem, but as it sounds like your initial problem is implementing a `Join` in LINQ, then check out [this section on Join Operators from the 101 LINQ Samples pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/vcsharp/ee908647).